# How do I add an item from a drop down list to a flex table?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use the button below to add the selected item in the drop down list to the flex table. Can someone either edit my existing code to make it work or show me the handler I need to use?

I would like the item to be placed in the first column and row of the flex table.

Link to spreadsheet where script is contained: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgBEgZ2go9LydEM2MmV2dm5BNmtpOTNkRlF3cXg4N0E)

```
//Create button that adds items to flex table   
    var button = app.createButton('+');
```

PS:  I am an aerospace engineer and not a programmer. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: I think you should try to provide a shortened version of your code that shows the point you need to clarify... the link you provide need too much work to simply make it work and is probably beyond what this forum is supposed to provide as support. I understand you're not a software programmer but if you wrote this code you can probably write a significant subset of it as well.

Comment: Hello Serge, I will be sure to do that next time. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code that shows how to do what you want. Basically, create a handler that has the listbox as a callback element. Then, in the handler function, reference the active listbox entry with e.parameter.listBoxName to use it.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var listBox = app.createListBox();
  listBox.addItem("item 1").addItem("item 2").addItem("item 3").setName("myListBox");

  var handler = app.createServerHandler("buttonHandler");
  // pass the listbox into the handler function as a parameter
  handler.addCallbackElement(listBox);

  var table = app.createFlexTable().setId("myTable");

  var button = app.createButton("+", handler);
  app.add(listBox);
  app.add(button);
  app.add(table);
  return app;
}

function buttonHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(0).insertCell( 0, 0).setText( 0, 0, e.parameter.myListBox);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kalyan.  This is perfect.  Could you also show me how to make it add each item below the previous entry?

Comment: See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467009/how-to-make-the-last-item-added-to-a-flextable-return-directly-underneath-the-pr)